# Liquibase freezes in update

Tags: csv, updates, liquibase

Use Liquibase 3.5.3

Export data like:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom;
liquibase
--driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.1:1521:base_name"
--username=user
--password=pass
--defaultSchemaName=schema_name
--changeLogFile=table_name.yml
--promptForNonLocalDatabase=false
--logLevel=DEBUG
--logFile="logs/table_name.log"
--diffTypes="data"
--dataOutputDirectory=csv_out
generateChangeLog
--includeObjects="table_name"
```

Everything is done just fine!
Incidentally, I create a common file for the future import of one command (main.yml).
file looks like:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include: { file: TABLE_1.yml }
  - include: { file: TABLE_2.yml }
  - include: { file: TABLE_3.yml }
  - include: { file: TABLE_4.yml }
  - include: { file: TABLE_5.yml }
  - include: { file: TABLE_6.yml }
...
```

I'm trying to import the command:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m";
liquibase
--driver=org.postgresql.Driver
--url="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.2:5432/base_name"
--username=user
--password=pass
--defaultSchemaName=schema_name
--changeLogFile=main.yml
--databaseChangeLogTableName=databasechangedatalog
--databaseChangeLogLockTableName=databasechangedataloglock
--logFile="logs_import/main.log"
--promptForNonLocalDatabase=false
update
```

liquibase freezes on TABLE_6. I waited more than 8 hours. NO ERROS. NO LINES in DB. Only blocking entry in databasechangedataloglock.

Previous tables (1..5) done fine.
Sizes of CSV files:

- TABLE_1.csv - 234 b
- TABLE_2.csv - 1972036 b
- TABLE_3.csv - 37455 K
- TABLE_4.csv - 7825580 b
- TABLE_5.csv - 2129993 b
- TABLE_6.csv - 307498 K

The first 5 tables were imports in 5 minutes.
I do not believe that 6 table can importing with more than 8 hours and this is normal.

The top says that Java (liquibase) in the system that does something, memory and the processor change the indicators.

What's wrong? Why there are no errors?

Comment: Nathan Voxland, where are you? need your help!

Comment: I guess it would help if you could say what is in `TABLE_6.csv`.

Comment: `"ID","TME_REG","CLL_UID","TEL","DST","CLL_ST","SRV_OWN_ID","SRV_EXE_ID","ORD_ID","ORD_CNT","CLT_TPE"
"16058601","2017-02-07T17:16:37.000","1486477233.71564","9087173387","2205024","2","251","246","26767286","1","0"
"16058603","2017-02-07T17:16:43.000","1486477248.71572","9091291617","2205024","2","251","246","26767289","1","0"
"16058604","2017-02-07T17:16:43.000","1486477241.71568","9121244823","2205773","2","641","277","26767290","1","0"`
And then in that spirit ...